# Can't get composer work on wampserver 2.5: host not known

Tags: php, composer-php, wampserver, host

I did a fresh install of wampserver 2.5 64bit on windows 7 64bit with php 5.5.12.
After that, I appendend php path to the window's PATH environment variable.

Then i installed composer using the installer found at the official site.

When i try to run any command, i get a host error, for example:

> composer create-project --prefer-dist -s dev SOMEPACKAGE
>
> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>   The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host sconosciuto.
>   failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host sconosciuto.
>
> composer diagnose
>
> Checking platform settings: FAIL
>   The xdebug extension is loaded, this can slow down Composer a little.
>   Disabling it when using Composer is recommended, but should not cause issues beyond slowness.
>   Checking git settings: OK
>   Checking http connectivity: FAIL
>   [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host sconosciuto.
>   failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host sconosciuto.
>   Checking disk free space: OK

Host sconosciuto means "Host not known"
Did someone know how can i get composer work?
I'm not behind a proxy and my hosts file only has one record:
127.0.0.1       localhost

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have not activated `opensssl.dll` and `php_curl` in the `php.ini` that is used by the PHP CLI ( Command line interface )

In Wampserver there are 2 php.ini files, one used by Apche and one used by PHP when run from the command line.

Check `\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini` and make sure all the extensions you will need to use with Composer are activated, `php_openssl` is definitely one of them `php_curl` is another.

Also with WAMPServer it is bad practice to put the folder with the PHP executable on the Windows PATH environmant variable, as with WAMPServer you can switch versions of PHP easily.

I use this batch file

FILENAME = phppath.cmd

```
echo off
if %1.==. GOTO DEFAULT
ECHO ----------Setting up PHP%1---------------------------------
PATH=%PATH%;d:\wamp\bin\php\php%1
php -v
GOTO COMPOSER

:DEFAULT
echo Taking the default version php5.5.12
echo ----------DEFAULT----------------------------------------------
PATH=%PATH%;d:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12
php -v

:COMPOSER
echo Make Composer work
PATH=%PATH%;D:\wamp\composer
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Instead of adding php to the Windows PATH put this file in a folder that is already on your path, `C:\windows` if you dont have any of your own already on the PATH.

To put the default PHP version of the path just call it like :-

```
>phppath
```

To add a specific PHP version ( assuming you have more than one installed into WAMPServer call it like :-

```
>phppath 5.5.14
```

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

*update: in cli i can't even connect to database in localhost*

Then your 2 ini files are not the same or you are loading one from somewhere else.

Do this from a command window

```
php --ini
```

It should look like this

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

So check you dont have a rouge php.ini in the `C:\windows` folder, or anywhere else that may show up in the list. The php.ini should only be in `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini`

Comment: Both php_openssl and php_curl were already activated.

One strange thing is that the php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo problem occurs only on cli, but php.ini is the same in both cli and apache..

(thanks for phppath.cmd suggestion)

Comment: I assume you are actually connected to the internet when you execute the composer commands?

Comment: yes, but the problem is with every hostname. For example, if i run the following command I get the same error:

`> php -r "echo file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');" | php`

Comment: Do you have `allow_url_fopen = On` in your `php.ini'?

Comment: I have seen some solutions to this suggesting that if your IPADDRESS is in a blacklist this can happen. Is your router on a static ip or do you get another ip when you reboot your router? If its dynamic try rebooting the router, and check it gets another address.

Comment: My router has dynamic ip. I also get this problem both at my work router and at my home router (in two different places). Also in the same LAN, my colleague with the same installation of wampserver (and the same php.ini configuration) does not have any problem.

Comment: Have you checked for some clues in the php error log.

Comment: in php_error.log there are the same errors i got in cli